# How to get Docker version in .NET Core

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to determine the version of the docker in my .NET Core backend. I already had the idea to create an own environment variable in docker-compose, but I don't know how to get the information like `docker -v` and pass it to the application when it starts.
I hope that one of you can give me a tip.

Part of the docker-compose

```
ports:
 - "5000:80"

environment:
  DOCKER_VERSION: ... docker -v ...

volumes:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be simply possible, according to the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) and to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4081).

One possiblity is to set an enviromnental variable in the outside that holds the output of `docker -v`, then use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) feature provided by compose (`${VARIABLE}`).